# Equvalent option for Python gRPC server max_workers and maximum_concurrent_rpcs in C++ gRPC sync server

Tags: c++, grpc, grpc-python

This is a gRPC server in python:

```
server = grpc.server(
    thread_pool=futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32),
    maximum_concurrent_rpcs=100,
)
```

In Python if the server is processing *maximum_concurrent_rpcs* requests the next request will be rejected immediately.

If *max_workers* is less than *maximum_concurrent_rpcs* there are *max_workers* number of threads that are processing request and if there is no free thread the next requests go to a queue until a thread will be free and pick up a request from the queue to process. The maximum size of the queue is 
*maximum_concurrent_rpcs*.

**My question is what is the equivalent option in *sync server* C++ gRPC?**

**1. How to set the thread pool size and how to set the queue size to put extra requests in it after the thread pool has no any free thread?**

**2. How set set a timeout for queued requests?**

There is a *SetMaxThreads* option but it seems that it works as if both *max_workers* and *maximum_concurrent_rpcs* are set to this option.

```
grpc::ResourceQuota rq;
rq.SetMaxThreads(100);
builder.SetResourceQuota(rq);
```

I see options below but they are not working in a way that I expect.

```
builder.SetSyncServerOption(ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::NUM_CQS, 3);
builder.SetSyncServerOption(ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::MIN_POLLERS, 1);
builder.SetSyncServerOption(ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::MAX_POLLERS, 5);
builder.SetSyncServerOption(ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::CQ_TIMEOUT_MSEC, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS limits the max number of requests that will be handled timely: "Maximum number of concurrent incoming streams to allow on a http2 connection." https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/47a06ace92d0db299e6fa9ecc9a9d26db8d85c62/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h#L150

If more requests come, they will be buffered. The buffer size is limited by the resource quota (currently, only the memory quota).

The buffered requests will time out when their deadline (specified by application) is reached.

Comment: How can I set GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS for a sync server? Could you provide a snippet?

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/0bdeca47b620a7011cb6114026739be330518562/src/cpp/server/load_reporter/load_reporting_service_server_builder_option.cc#L31 is an example of how to use the server builder option to configure a server. I think it doesn't matter if it's a sync or async server.